# How to track cube (with each side image changed) using vuforia or any other Argument?

Tags: opencv, vuforia

I'm learning vuforia these days (https://developer.vuforia.com/).
I wonder how to track a rubik's cube ( with each side color changed).

As the [Getting Started](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started) said , maybe I could use the `Multi-Targets` to repesent the cube. But each side of rubik's cube is different. I do not know how to upload the `cuboid images` for each sides..

Is there any other way ? Please show me some tips.
Thanks!

Comment: Check this code: https://github.com/isdaniarf/cube-tracker

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Thanks a lot